# Add elements from array to object to format fusionchart data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fusioncharts

I want to format  the data of my fusion chart based on scope variable.
I have a function which gets dates and stock values assigned to this dates.
So I have 2 arrays:

```
dates =  [2017-04-28, 2017-04-27, 2017-04-26, 2017-04-25]
stockValues = [150.25, 147.7, 146.56, 146.49]
```

What I want to do is to create a new object which looks like this:

```
data: [{
  "label": "2017-04-28",
  "value": "150.25"
  },
  {
  "label": "2017-04-27",
  "value": "147.7"
  },
  ... //and so on
  ]
```

I managed to come up with following code:

```
$scope.getStockData = function(stockID) {
                $http.get('/stock', {
                    params : {
                        stockID : encodeURI(stockID)
                    }
                }).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.stock = response.data;
                    var data={};
                    $scope.data={};
                    angular.forEach(response.data.dates,function(value){
                        data["label"] = value;
                    })
                    angular.forEach(response.data.stockValues,function(value){
                        data["value"] = value;
                    })

                    $scope.data = data;

                }, function(response) {
                    $scope.showError = true;
                }).finally(function() {
                  });
            };
```

The problem is that this solution creates object which looks like this:

```
{"label":"2017-04-25","value":"146.49"}
```

So it takes only the last values from array. 
How can I make my object look the way I want it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```js
const dates =  ['2017-04-28', '2017-04-27', '2017-04-26', '2017-04-25']
const stockValues = ['150.25', '147.7', '146.56', '146.49']

const r = dates.map((d, i) => Object.assign({
  label: d,
  value: stockValues[i]
}))

console.log(JSON.stringify(r, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you must initialize an array, and the push at the right location.

```
$scope.getStockData = function(stockID) {
    $http.get('/stock', {
        params : {
            stockID : encodeURI(stockID)
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.stock = response.data;
        var data=[];
        $scope.data=[];
        angular.forEach(response.data.dates,function(value, i){
            data[i]["label"] = value;
        })
        angular.forEach(response.data.stockValues,function(value, i){
            data[i]["value"] = value;
        })

        $scope.data = data;

    }, function(response) {
        $scope.showError = true;
    }).finally(function() {
      });
};
```